# Display "0" or "Null" in Application

Tags: display

I need suggest about displaying data in an report application. This reporting application gets data from transaction application. If I haven't inputted several data on certain date in transaction application, what is better, display this data as 0 or Null?

Comment: Depends on the context. The difference in coding between 0 and null, is that 0 is "something", while null represents the absence of any information.

if something is 0, we can conclude it is at least a number (thus, still carrying information), but with null it marks that there is no information available to give context to the value of something.

Comment: This is primarily opinion based, but personally, I would say that in a report, you would never display null - it doesn't mean anything to anyone outside the IT community.  Arguably, if you don't have the data, then displaying 0 would also be inaccurate.  You may be best leaving the value empty if you're trying to indicate you don't have the data

Comment: I wouldn't show NULL, and as other comments say, it depends entirely on the context.  For the field "How many cookies were eaten", 0 (zero) is a perfectly acceptable answer but more importantly is a *different* answer to 'No value was given' (i.e. NULL).  Personally I'd *normally* want to show 'N/A' or '<unknown>' or something rather than NULL to show that difference, but that's very much dependent on what the users want/expect and whether that sort of distinction really matters or not.. In other words, context is everything.

Comment: Thanks guys, yeah I mean not "NULL", but empty value